# How do I get the owner of an Orchard ContentItem programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

What I am looking for is equivalent to this:

```
IUser owner = someContentItem.Owner;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IUser owner = someContentItem.As<ICommonPart>().Owner;`.

Your item needs to have `CommonPart` attached (which should almost always be the case) in order to use this.